# Starting Activity clicking TextView

Tags: onclick, textview, android

i think i'm a little bit stupid to creating a textView with a link. :D

I tried different examples, but not one will works fine. Can anyone help me, how i can start a new activity by clicking on a textView?

Thanks a lot :D